# Android How to consume all the touchevent by te LinearLayout

Tags: android, touch, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like that.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ....>
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
           ...............
           ..............
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box2"
        android:background="#c0000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
           .............
           .............
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Box2 is showing above Box1, and due to semi-transparent color of Box2, Box1 is visible partially. Now I want to make consume all the touch event by box2, so that the `Button`s and `EditText`s in Box2 does not work. How it can be done by java code?

Answer (score 7):

You shold set touch listener on layout like:

```
your_liner_layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){                  
       return true;
    }
});
```

This will consume the event and prevent the propagation of event

Answer (score 4):

my understanding is that box2 (and its child views) should not be clickable, while box1 should be. so add attribute clickable="false" in box2 relativeLayout and clickable='''true'' in box1 .

else provide additional detail about your prob.